# Make unique array and add the amount in php

Tags: php

I have to make the array to unique array list if the invoice_products_id is same and for the same invoice_products_id i have add the amount. I am able to make it unique but amount is not adding.

```
 0 =>{
      'id' => 9,
      'invoice_products_id' => 2,
      'amount' => 1.8,
     },
 1 =>{
      'id' => 10,
      'invoice_products_id' => 3,
      'amount' => 2,
     },
 2 =>{
      'id' => 11,
      'invoice_products_id' => 2,
      'amount' => 1.1,
     },
 3 =>{
      'id' => 12,
      'invoice_products_id' => 3,
      'amount' => 1.2,
     },
```

code:

```
         $invtax=[];
          foreach($invoiceProduct['invoice_taxes'] as $taxkey=>$taxval){

            $ref=$taxval->invoice_products_id;
            if(isset($invtax[$ref])){
                $invtax[$ref]->amount+=$taxval->amount;
            }else{
                $invtax[$ref]=$taxval;
            }
        }
```

result:

```
 2 =>{
      'id' => 11,
      'invoice_products_id' => 2,
      'amount' => 2.9,
     },
 3 =>{
      'id' => 12,
      'invoice_products_id' => 3,
      'amount' => 1.2,
     },
```

expected:

```
 2 =>{
      'id' => 11,
      'invoice_products_id' => 2,
      'amount' => 2.9,

     },
 3 =>{
      'id' => 12,
      'invoice_products_id' => 3,
      'amount' => 3.2,
               },
```

Comment: Not that it seems to change much, but `taxes_master_id` or `id`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca only amount is updating based on invoice_products_id

Comment: I was just pointing out that your code doesn't match your objects' structure.

Comment: In the code `taxes_master_id` should be `invoice_products_id`.

Comment: From the result it looks like the if-condition is never true. Although I do not see why this should make a difference here, have you tried using `array_key_exists` as a condition instead of `isset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_walk`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) functions

See here for live example: https://3v4l.org/rXXR9

Input

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [
        'id' => 9,
        'invoice_products_id' => 2,
        'amount' => 1.8,
    ],[
        'id' => 10,
        'invoice_products_id' => 3,
        'amount' => 2,
    ],[
        'id' => 11,
        'invoice_products_id' => 2,
        'amount' => 1.1,
    ],[
        'id' => 12,
        'invoice_products_id' => 3,
        'amount' => 1.2,
    ],
];
```

Program

```
<?php    
$assorted_heap = [];


$filter_function = function($v, $k) {
    global $assorted_heap;
    if (isset($assorted_heap[$v['invoice_products_id']])) {
        $assorted_heap[$v['invoice_products_id']][1] += $v['amount'];
        return false;
    } else {
        $assorted_heap[$v['invoice_products_id']] = [$k, $v['amount']];
    }
    return true;
};

$walk_function = function(&$v, $k) {
    global $assorted_heap;
    $v['amount'] = $assorted_heap[$v['invoice_products_id']][1];
};

$new_arr = array_filter($arr,
  $filter_function,
  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH 
);
array_walk($new_arr, $walk_function);
unset($assorted_heap);

print_r($new_arr);
```

Output

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [id] => 9 
            [invoice_products_id] => 2 
            [amount] => 2.9 
        ) 
    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [id] => 10 
            [invoice_products_id] => 3 
            [amount] => 3.2 
        )
)
```